# PDFs not rendering perfectly after chrome 92 version update(same with firefox version 90 and above)

Tags: google-chrome, pdf.js, react-pdf

I am facing this issue with react-pdf library. With this new chrome 92 version update i am supposed to get these table filled with data but instead i get it empty. this happened with couple of pdfs.
I am ussing React version 16.9.x

- React version 16.9.x
- react-pdf 3.0.4
- Chrome version 92.0.54xx, firefox version 90.0.2
  [pdffile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYJk7.png)
  I think it is somehow related to the pdfjs version